# Uso de 2 StreamBuilder al mismo tiempo

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Al momento de compilar usando 2 streambuilder para realizar dos consultas a firebase me marca el siguiente error:

```
The following _CastError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String,
dynamic>>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>,
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#21369):
Null check operator used on a null value
```

Estoy utilizando 2 por que uno es para una lista de videos en un carousel-slider y otro para un listado en un gridview, quiero realizar dos consultas diferentes, de hecho se realiza la consulta exitosamente y se muestra tal cual quiero pero me muestra muchos errores en terminal, y si utilizo un solo streambuider no me marca ningun error, pero no puedo hacer las dos consultas diferentes que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo mi codigo:

```
  body: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      const SizedBox(height: 5),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          const Text(
            "Lo Nuevo",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 200),
          InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const RecentVideos()));
              },
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: 180 * math.pi / 180,
                child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
              )),
        ],
      ),
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("videos")
            .orderBy('id', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot2) {
          return CarouselSlider.builder(
            carouselController: CarouselController(),
            itemCount: 5,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 120,
              viewportFraction: 0.4,
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              autoPlay: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int page) {
              String urlPic = snapshot2.data!.docs[index]['thumbnail'];
              String videoUrl = snapshot2.data!.docs[index]['videoUrl'];
              return Card(
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            MinVideoScreen(videoUrl: videoUrl)));
                  },
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: urlPic,
                            imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                                Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: imageProvider,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                child: Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.play_arrow,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 10),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          const Text(
            "Todo el Contenido",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 120),
          InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const AllVideos()));
              },
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: 180 * math.pi / 180,
                child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
              )),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 10),
      Flexible(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("videos")
              .orderBy('id')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            return GridView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                /* mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 0,*/
                childAspectRatio: (100 / 130),
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                String urlPic = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['thumbnail'];
                String videoUrl = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['videoUrl'];
                String videoName = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['nameVideo'];
                return Card(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  /* shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    ),*/
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              MinVideoScreen(videoUrl: videoUrl)));
                    },
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: CachedNetworkImage(
                              imageUrl: urlPic,
                              imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                                  Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: imageProvider,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: const Color.fromARGB(
                                            255, 10, 54, 155),
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                    child: const Icon(
                                      Icons.play_arrow,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 241, 241, 241),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(videoName,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style:
                                    const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no es que sean dos streambuilder, es que hay data nula, me imagino que pasa eso hasta que se obtiene la data.

Podrias agregar un cargando antes de generar el grid

```
builder: (context,
        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }return GridView.builder(...
```